# Add javascript to specific page? chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my manifest.json file I have my script.js setup to work on www.domain.com, but there is this element in script.js:

```
{
var snd = new Audio('link.mp3');
snd.play();
}
```

I want this to only work on www.domain.com/example.

Can I add something like

```
  snd.something(www.domain.com/example);
```

Or do I have to make a new .js file and link it to the specific page I want it to be in the manifest.json?

Comment: Is the mp3 file hosted at example.com? Then try `new Audio('http://example.com/link.mp3').play();`. Is it a static file that won't change in the future? Then add it to your extension and use `new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL('link.mp3').play();` (["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html) might be worth reading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if(window.location.href == "http://www.domain.com/example") {
    var snd = new Audio('link.mp3');
    snd.play();
}
```